# retrieving data from ftp with script

Tags: ftp

```
ftp 123.456
Name: anonymous
Password: password
binary
cd 001
get mfile.d.Z
```

I need to write a script which performs above codes to retrieve data automatically.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/FTP-3.html and this: http://linuxconfig.org/example-of-simple-bash-script-client

Comment: why not use wget?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ftplib

host = '127.0.0.1'
dir = '001'
filename = 'mdfile.d.z'

# connect

ftp = ftplib.FTP(host)

# login - anonymous by default
# use ftp.login("username", "password") if no anon access

ftp.login()

# change to desired dir

ftp.cwd(dir)

# fetch the file, and copy it to a file of the
# same name in the local pwd

with open(filename, 'wb') as local_file:
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR {}".format(filename), local_file.write)
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Can you elaborate? "didn't work" is a pretty broad statement.

Comment: my OS just freeze when I execute the script. Here the other way I tried, host='123.456'
Name='anonymous'
passw:'123456'
ftp $host , from here everything is ok but I don't know how I can write Name within script